# Encrypt & Decrypt password using Jasypt

Tags: java, security, passwords, jasypt

It's for a desktop app, so only I want basic login security and I though to use one function to encrypt password and another which I pass pass password from UI and hash save into db and returns true o false depends on if matches or not.

I try to use pooled version from official jasypt website, and I can encrypt but I don't know how to decrypt it.

```
//Function to encrypt password
public static String cifrarClave(String clave) {
    PooledStringDigester digester = new PooledStringDigester();
    digester.setPoolSize(4);
    digester.setAlgorithm("SHA-1");
    digester.setIterations(50000);
    digester.setSaltSizeBytes(32);

    //String return is hash that I save into db
    return digester.digest(clave);
}

//Function to decrypt password
//clave is old plain that user enter from UI and I want to compare from hash save it into db
public static boolean validarClave(String clave, String hash) {
    PooledStringDigester digester = new PooledStringDigester();
    digester.setPoolSize(4); 
    digester.setAlgorithm("SHA-1");
    digester.setIterations(50000);

    String digest = digester.digest(clave);

    //Always fails at that point, I get different hash from compare clave
    return digester.matches(digest, hash);
}
```

I'm a newbie in security, so I don't know much about security, I accept other suggestions or alternatives, I only want a working example.

Comment: Thanks jaja, I think fails because salt changes eacht tiem, I want to use for salt for example first two letters from user name so always I can know salt and I don't need to save apart. Problem here, is that I don't know how to encode, I read this article(http://www.jasypt.org/howtoencryptuserpasswords.html) but they don't give any example in code.

Comment: You **don't need** to decrypt the password, just hash what the user entered and check the hash with the one from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the jasypt's `matches(message, digest)` function incorrectly when you are calling it with two hash digests instead of the plaintext message and the previously computed digest.

In your `validarClave()`, you're first unnecessarily computing a digest from the user's plaintext password (`clave`) which you then pass to the matcher:

```
String digest = digester.digest(clave);
//Always fails at that point, I get different hash from compare clave
return digester.matches(digest, hash);
```

Your method will work correctly if you simply pass the plaintext password to the matcher, as follows:

```
digester.matches(clave, hash);
```

More info is available at jasypt's [javadocs](http://www.jasypt.org/api/jasypt/1.9.2/org/jasypt/digest/PooledStringDigester.html#matches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and [code examples](http://www.jasypt.org/easy-usage.html).